# How to reset FIND function result before looping to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask if you can help with the code below. On every sheet in my workbook there is the same kind of a table, however on each sheet the table has different location and values. I need to go through all sheets, search for table values on every sheet and then do some other operations with the values. I use Find function to determine header of the table and subsequently table range. The Find function does not work properly though as it keeps found address of "Header" cell from the first sheet for every other sheet. Is there any way to reset the found header address value before looping to another sheet? Thank you in advance.

```
Sub FindInDynamicRanges()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell, FoundTab, TabEntries As Excel.Range
Dim FirstAddr As String
Dim FirstRow, LastRow As Long

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'Find all occurences of any table value on all sheets in dynamic ranges
For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Find "Header" cell
    Set FoundCell = ws.Columns(2).Find(What:="Header", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    MsgBox FoundCell.Address

    'Set number of first entry row and last entry row
    FirstRow = FoundCell.Row + 1
    LastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    ws.Range("B" & FirstRow & ":B" & LastRow).Name = "TabEntries"
    MsgBox Range("TabEntries").Address

    With ws.Range("TabEntries")
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Set FoundTab = ws.Range("TabEntries").Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not FoundTab Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundTab.Address
    End If

    Do Until FoundTab Is Nothing
            'do some staff with found values

        Set FoundTab = ws.Range("TabEntries").FindNext(After:=FoundTab)

        If FoundTab.Address = FirstAddr Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as it keeps found address of "Header" cell from the first sheet for every other sheet.

That is because you are telling it to...

```
For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

You don't need that `Set ws = ActiveSheet`

When you say `For Each ws`, the `ws` is automatically initialized. So just remove the second line.

Comment: Works now perfectly. Thank you, Siddharth. I tried whatever else and did not suppose it would be such a trifle. I will know for the future in any case.